# Power BI dataset relationships grayed out

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a Power BI dataset with the power BI REST API. There are 2 tables in this dataset.

Now, I'm creating a new report with data from this dataset (with Power BI Desktop).

The problem is that the "Manage relationships" command is grayed out. I have read somewhere that I should switch from a "connected live" dataset to an import dataset, but I'm not sure it applies in this case and I did not even find how to do it yet.

So, the question is: how can one enable the "Manage relationships" command for data coming from a Power BI dataset? Is it some flag I should set to a specific value when I create the dataset with the API? Or something to do in Power BI Desktop I've been unable to find up to now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a dataset created using the REST API, then it must be added to the report by using `Power BI Dataset` data source. This means that this is a live connection, in which the modeling is done at the data source itself (think of this as connected to a SSAS cube). In this case you have pretty limited options what you can do in the report (creating measures is pretty much everything you can do).

You can't switch to `Import` in this case. For importing, you must load the data from the data source used to fill this data set and bypass it completely.

If you are missing a relationship between the tables in the dataset, you can define it when creating the dataset, with json body like this:

```
{
    "name": "SalesData",
    "defaultMode": "Push",
    "tables": [
    {
      "name": "Customers",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "CustomerId",
          "dataType": "Int64"
        },
        {
          "name": "CustomerName",
          "dataType": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Orders",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "CustomerId",
          "dataType": "Int64"
        },
        {
          "name": "OrderDate",
          "dataType": "Datetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "Amount",
          "dataType": "Double"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "name": "FK_Orders_Customers",
      "fromTable": "Orders",
      "fromColumn": "CustomerId",
      "toTable": "Customers",
      "toColumn": "CustomerId",
      "crossFilteringBehavior": "bothDirections"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had also found out that I could add relationships when creating the dataset, but now I know that relationships can't be added inside of power bi desktop with this kind of dataset. best regards.

Comment: thank you! it helped me out of the dense of googling why relationship button is not enabled with Push Data.